# Optimized way to handle common groupby columns across different groupby operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the below dataframe

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
    A   B   X1  X2  Y
0   a1  b1  p   u   1.2
1   a1  b1  p   v   0.0
2   a1  b2  q   v   1.0
3   a2  b2  p   u   2.0
4   a2  b2  q   q   5.0
5   a2  b1  q   v   7.0
```

I need to `groupby` both `A,B,X1` and `A,B,X2` frequently, as below -

```
In [2]: df.groupby(['A','B','X1'])['Y'].sum()
```

```
In [3]: df.groupby(['A','B','X2'])['Y'].sum()
```

I am expecting that each time we do `groupby` some time is consumed in trying to identify the unique combinations across the columns constituting the group-keys. Hence, in the first `groupby` operation the unique combinations across `A,B,X1` are evaluated, while for the second `groupby` operation those across `A,B,X2` are checked.

1. **Is my above expectation correct?**
2. **If it is - is there a way to take advantage of the common group-keys `A,B` across all the `groupby` operations?**

***Some contextual assumptions:*** The number of distinct combinations across `A,B`, will be much higher than those found across `X1` or `X2`. There is no assumption of any non-null values in any column (whereby the flexibility of `groupby` in handling nulls in group-key columns becomes necessary). The columns of type `X1`, `X2`, and the type of aggregations that will be performed using a certain `DataFrameGroupBy` object, will be large in number (whereby the necessity of this optimization).

An ideal (hypothetical) solution, if at all there is a time-performance increment as per assumption, would have been -

```
In [4]: grp = df.groupby(['A','B'])
        grp[['X1','Y']].groupby('X1').sum()
Out[4]:
A   B   X1
a1  b1  p     1.2
    b2  q     1.0
a2  b1  q     7.0
    b2  p     2.0
        q     5.0
Name: Y, dtype: float64
```

but we cannot do a `groupby` on a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

Comment: Based on the given example, can you add the expected output to your post ?

Comment: @abokey `In [2]` and `In [3]` clarify the operation I want; `In [4]` is a hypothetical code explaining an idea. I want to know if there is some better way to take advantage of the apparent repetition between those two operations (2 and 3). Do I need to provide the outputs for those operations as well? I thought they would increase the length of the question, without adding any value to the crux of the query.

Comment: @abokey have included the expected output in `Out[4]:`.